# Sitecore - version created in other language when renaming

Tags: sitecore

So I've got this Sitecore content item right, and it's got one version in one language "en-AU".

I have 3 potential languages in the system "en", "en-AU" and "en-NZ".

I rename the item, right, and Sitecore creates a new version in "en".

I delete the "en" version and rename again, same result.. a new version is created .. and again... and again .. see where I'm going with this? And again!

Why would it do that? I thought it was a problem with my pipeline processor, but I turned it off and it still happens!

Any ideas would be welcome.

Comment: Please report this to our support team(http://support.sitecore.net). That's the best way to see if it is a reproducible scenario and if we can fix it for you very soon.

Comment: Was this ever logged as a Sitecore bug? It is still reproducible with version `6.4.1.101221`.

Comment: Im experiencing the same problem with Sitecore 7.0. (rev. 130424)

Answer (score 1):

What's the default language on your Sitecore user account? (Sitecore > Control Panel > Preferences)

If you create a new item, what language is it created in?